# Why does path-independence of limits hold in the complex numbers but not in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, partial-derivative, analytic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

In my studies of complex differentiation, I've come across the following paradox concerning real partial derivatives:

In proofs of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, the fact that the limit
\begin{align*}
\frac{df}{dz}\Bigg\vert_{z=z_0}=\lim_{\Delta z\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z_0+\Delta z)-f(z_0)}{\Delta z}
\end{align*}

converges to the same value, independent of how $\Delta z$ approaches $0$. Using this fact, the equality

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Bigg\vert_{z=z_0}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z_0+\Delta x)-f(z_0)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{i\Delta y\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z_0+i\Delta y)-f(z_0)}{i\Delta y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigg\vert_{z=z_0}
\end{align}

is arrived at, and is used to prove that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold wherever $f$ is analytic.

The question, then, is: why does this equality of partial derivatives with the standard derivative, as well as with each other, $(\frac{df}{dz}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$) hold when considering differentiation in $\mathbb{C}$, but not when considering multivariable differentiation in $\mathbb{R}^2$? For clearly, a function with a domain $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ are differentiable at many points where yield their partial derivatives differ: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\neq\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, which apparently cannot occur in the case of complex partial derivatives. I'm not even quite sure what the analogous quantity of $\frac{df}{dz}$ would be in the real case.

What accounts for the difference in these two cases? What attribute does the complex plane possess that is absent in the real plane?

Thanks very much for reading - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Being complex differentiable is a much stronger constraint that the $u,v$ being separately differentiable.

Comment: You most definitely do not mean $\partial f/\partial x = \partial f/\partial y$.

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2990869/72031

Comment: You should go re-read your proof of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, because, as @TedShifrin points out, they do not say what you've written here.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I'm afraid you're mistaken. The many proofs I've read of Cauchy-Riemann use precisely this property to draw the equality between the $x$ and $y$ partial derivatives. For reference, see texts by Gamelin, Hille, and Brown and Churchill. The equality is easily drawn. If you believe I'm in error, feel free to show me exactly why.

Comment: In the C-R equations as stated in the question, a factor of $-i$ on the partial with respect to $y$ has been lost.

Comment: @WilliamMastin - You've got the spirit of C-R right, but you've completely mis-read the details. In particular, you should be looking at the real and imaginary parts of $f$ if you want to understand, and also, saying something like $\frac{df}{dz} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, well, no, C-R doesn't say that. It does say some things that might look like that if you glance at them, but not that. However, you seem very confident, so good luck!

Answer (score 2):

More of a ramble than an answer, but may highlight one key difference from $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is that elements of $\mathbb{C}$ are scalars.

In both cases we have
$f(z+h)- f(z) \approx f'(z)h $ - nothing distinguishing here.

Consider a rotation $\rho \in \mathbb{C}$, that is $|\rho|=1$.

Then $f(z+\rho h)- f(z)) \approx f'(z) \rho h = \rho f'(z) h \approx \rho (f(z+h)-f(z))$. That is, the effect of rotating the 'perturbation' $h$ is the same rotating the effect of the perturbation.

This does not hold in general in $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ mappings.
For the same to happen with a rotation $R$ would require $R f'(x) = f'(x) R$, and the $2\times 2$ matrices which commute with any rotation $R$ are of the form
$\lambda \begin{bmatrix} c & s \\ -s & c \end{bmatrix}$, for real scalars satisfying $c^s+s^2 =1$. This has the same form as required by the Cauchy Riemann equations, $\begin{bmatrix} u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} u_x & u_y \\ -u_y & u_x \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$The calculation in the question loses a factor of $-i$ at the last equality; it should read:
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\dd f}{\dd x}\bigg\vert_{z=z_{0}}
  &= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(z_{0} + \Delta x) - f(z_{0})}{\Delta x} \\
  &= \lim_{i\Delta y\to 0}\frac{f(z_{0} + i\Delta y) - f(z_{0})}{i\Delta y} \\
  &= -i\frac{\dd f}{\dd y}\bigg\vert_{z=z_{0}}.
\end{align*}

To see why, recall that by using notation for real partial derivatives we're identifying complex numbers $z = x + iy$ with Cartesian pairs $(x, y)$. Under this identification, we have
\begin{align*}
  \lim_{i\Delta y\to 0}\frac{f(z_{0} + i\Delta y) - f(z_{0})}{i\Delta y}
  &= \frac{1}{i} \lim_{i\Delta y\to 0}\frac{f(z_{0} + i\Delta y) - f(z_{0})}{\Delta y} \\
  &= -i \lim_{i\Delta y\to 0}\frac{f(x_{0}, y_{0} + \Delta y) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})}{\Delta y}\qquad\text{(n.b. $y_{0} + \Delta y$)} \\
  &= -i\frac{\dd f}{\dd y}\bigg\vert_{(x,y)=(x_{0},y_{0})} \\
  &= -i\frac{\dd f}{\dd y}\bigg\vert_{z=z_{0}}.
\end{align*}