# what is the difference between vector calculus and complex analysis with respect to derivative?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, vector-fields

For example,$ \begin{align}
    \vec{f} &= \begin{bmatrix}
           u(x,y) \\
           v(x,y) \\
           \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}$   could be recongnized as $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y),z \in \mathbb{C}$,In vector calculus:its derivative is$ \begin{align}
    D\vec{f} &= \begin{bmatrix}
           u_{x}& u_{y} \\
           v_{x}& v_{y} \\
           \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}$,but in complex analysis，its derivative is:$f^{'}(z)=u_{x}+iv_{x}$.Both are derived from $ \lim_{z \to z_{0}} \frac{f(z)-f(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}$  .why does it become so different?Do they have some relations?

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann...

Comment: [Scalar field derivative. Real vs Complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4091888/26369) might also be helpful.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I'd prefer to say that Cauchy-Riemann is more like a consequence of definitions of the complex derivative, not the reason they become different.